# How can I get my ceiling fan lights working again?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

After my light kit on my hunter type 2 fan stopped working I determined there is power entering this device (white wire) but none exiting it (pink wire). The pink wire runs to the pull chain for the lights.  I went so far as to buy another fan assembly with new light kit and replace the whole thing but I have the same problem. Fan works, lights don't.  Same issue power into the device , nothing out?  Any ideas?   I have replaced the fan for now with a 5 bulb ( 40 watt each) light fixture which is working fine.  Frustrating.....

Comment: So you are saying that the lights and fan both used to work and now stopped working? Does this fan electrical box have two power feeds coming to it? Is it possible that the circuit breaker for one circuit is open? Did the fan vibrate or swing around a lot in use such that the electrical wires could have developed an open circuit inside the insulation. (One way to break off a wire is to bend it back and forth).

Comment: You are going to have to add quite a bit more information, if you want an answer that might actually help you. A diagram of how you're wiring the fan/light, might be a good start. The amount, and colors of the wires that are in the fixture box would also help.

Comment: Power "entering but not exiting" violates [Kirchhoff's Current Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29). :)

Answer (score 1):

There should be black, white and green (or bare) wires at the fan.

The green or bare connects to all metal work-box and/or green screws.

The white, neutral connects to the fan white and the light white.

The black goes to the light via any switch it may have.

Answer (score -1):

I tested all my wires connection to connection, found out the pink wire was the problem.

Comment: Please give more detail about how you determined the pink wire was the problem, and what you did to fix it. Thanks!